# lisp defclass macro problem

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Bit of background, I'm a total lisp noob, only started a few weeks ago, but I've been developing in other langs for years. Logic no problem, lisp, problem.

I'm trying to write a macro that will define two clsql classes for me to get around a problem with the library. I'd like the classes to be named `x` and `x-insert`` , so within the macro I'd like the macro to compute the symbol name of x-insert, but I'm having difficulity doing this. My attempt is below, but i'm stumped on two things.

How do I get it to create the class names. If i remove the space in `,class -insert`, it wont eval, which I understand, so I presume I'm missing some straightforward way to tell it to ignore the space,and create the name as a single word, and the second problem is getting it to create two classes, not one, as its only expanding the last part of the macro from what I can see using macro expand.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way altogether, so feel free to kick me in the right direction.

```
(defmacro gen-pair (class base-slots pkey-slot base-table)
  `(clsql:def-view-class ,class -insert()
     (
      ,base-slots
     )
     (:base-table ,base-table)
   )

  `(clsql:def-view-class ,class (,class -insert)
     (
      ,pkey-slot
     )
     (:base-table ,base-table)
   )
)
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this lisp style guide while you're at it: http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt

Comment: Strongly agree with the suggestion of looking at a Lisp style guide.  This chapter on PCL might help clear up some of your misconceptions about how macros work. http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html

Comment: thanks for the links guys. will check em out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is difficult to begin an explanation here, since you seem to have a
whole stack of misconceptions.

First question (how to compose symbol names): Lisp macros do not
operate on *text* but on *code*.  In a backquote form, `,class`
evaluates to the code passed into the `class` parameter of the macro,
most likely a class name in this case.  Writing another symbol after
that does not magically merge the symbol names; why should it?  If you
want to compose a new symbol name, you have to construct it:

```
,(intern (string-upcase (concatenate 'string
                                     (symbol-name class)
                                     "-insert")))
```

Second question (why it seems to expand only the second part): the
contents of a `defmacro` form are evaluated in an implicit `progn`
(that is why it does not complain about an invalid number of arguments
here).  The return value of the last form is the return value of the
whole `defmacro` form.  In this case, the return value is the code
produced by that backquote form.  A macro defines a function that
expands a form into a new form; you cannot expand it into two
unrelated forms.  You have to produce a `progn` form that contains the
two forms you want to have.

Third question (why your code looks so different from what Lispers
write): do not throw around parentheses like nail clippings.  There
are several Lisp style guides flying around on the net.  Read them.
*Wer die Form beherrscht, kann mit ihr spielen* (roughly: when you
know the proper way, you can play with it).

Fourth question (how to come around the perceived limitation of
clsql): you could ask that question directly, no?  What limitation do
you mean?

Comment: "do not throw around parentheses like nail clippings" -- If he doesn't know what you mean, this sentence isn't going to help him understand anything.  Heck, I've been using Lisp for over 15 years (and English quite a bit longer than that) and I don't think *I* understand what you mean.  (Do people tend to throw nail clippings far apart a lot?)

Comment: @svante: I'd say that while the STRING-UPCASE woulpd be necessary in your case, wouldn't (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name class) (symbol-name '-insert))) be a better solution, in that it'd work even in common lisp environments using a different read-table (without, say, case-smashing)?

Comment: Another option that gives you a bit more flexibility is read-from-string.  This allows you to do something like: (read-from-string (format nil "~a-insert" (symbol-name class)).

Comment: @Vatine:  I just gave example code that follows the default convention.  Your solution has the disadvantage that the symbol `'-insert` will be interned, too.  I like Andrew Myers' `read-from-string` form.

Comment: My real problem is a problem with clsql and inserting on an ODBC datasource, with obtaining the auto inc identity field after the insert. I had a friend(real lisp guy) look into the problem, and he said its a problem with CLSQL,and a limitation,(works for mysql,not for ODBC). He suggested using something like this, which does work, but requires me to write two classes every time i define a class. I dont want to have to write them by hand if if I can avoid it, as they only differ slightly, and I was hoping a macro would be a candidate to save me here.

Comment: @Svante: Make it '#:-insert and you get no interning... :)